# how to add wordpress poll in magento?

Tags: php, wordpress, magento

I want to include wordpress poll to magento site, fishpig module is integrate with magento site and i've also install wordpress poll, but how we can display wordpress poll functionality to magento frontend, e.g. wordpress poll look and its ajax based functionality and its validation and all things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a Magento poll module to do this, Fishpig is designed more to display Magento products in a Wordpress page, it's not so strong at displaying Wordpress content in Magento.

You could contact the Fishpig developer (Ben) - help at fishpig dot co dot uk for free advice and/or paid assistance.

Answer (score -1):

please go to

```
 admin/system/configuration/advanced/
```

and enable Mage_poll